# Is it dangerous to eat a mutated eggplant descended from a radioactive ancestor?

Tags: human-biology, botany

What is the risk, if any, associated with eating a 100th-generation mutated eggplant derived from a radioactive ancestor?

In another word, is that possible that organic toxin will be produced by the mutated plant and is it a good idea to plant it in America? These plant seems very beautiful to me! Ha Ha

Note: The descendant eggplant is not radioactive.

Motivation: There are many mutated eggplants around Japanese power plants.

Comment: If it is not radioactive, why should it be dangerous? Mutations are occuring always and we also introduce changes in plants by selective breeding. Assuming that no toxins are produced, I would say there is no risk about these plants.

Comment: What mutations happened?

Comment: @Chris non-radioactive plants can be dangerous for many reasons. Toxins, pharmacology, for example. Without more information about the plants, we can't really answer this question.

Comment: @Articuno That's why I wrote "assuming no toxins are produced"...

Comment: That doesn't add any info though. That's like saying "assuming there is no risk about these plants, I would say there is no risk about these plants." I was answering your question about "if it is not radioactive. .."

Comment: @Articuno - But people complaining about genetically engineered food already, i will be surprised if that anything is not much severe than the normal genetic modified plant...

Comment: @Chris - REad the above comment

Comment: @user5479 You mean about genetically engineered food? Actually all our main food plants are modified since we settled some 8000 years ago. Until very recently this was done by selecting and breeding but essentially this modified the plants, too. So I don't see a reason to panic about genetic modifications when they are tested and safe.

Comment: @Chris - I mean terrorist could modify our food possibly

Comment: @user5479 Of course this would be possible, but how likely is that? That would first need the expertise to make the changes, than they need to propagate the plants to cause widespread poisoning. And when it is detected, the counter measure is rather easy: Discard all plants which might be contaminated. Packing a car with explosives is more easy and brings more fear, I would say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's always possible that a mutated eggplant will produce a new toxin, this is very unlikely. I don't know how much higher the mutation rate is near Fukushima than in general but the difference can't be huge. Even if it's, say, 5 or 10 times higher than normal (I'm making up these numbers), the risk is still tiny. Actually, plant breeders sometimes use radiation to produce more variety to work with and we don't worry about that.